# VB.NET Move XML Child to Parent

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

With the XML example of...

```
<records>
    <record>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>name</name>
        <related>
            <relatedToID>1</relatedToID>
            <relatedToName>some name</relatedToName>
        </related>
    </record>
</records>
```

How would I go about moving `relatedToId` and `relatedToName` to the name level as `name` so that the new XML string would be...

```
<records>
    <record>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>name</name>
        <relatedToID>1</relatedToID>
        <relatedToName>some name</relatedToName>
    </record>
</records>
```

I think it has something to do with XPath or something similar but am having trouble understanding how to do this. The XML is already loaded as a string in the variable `result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XElement

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' to load from a URI
    '   xe = XElement.Load("path here")
    ' for testing use a literal
    xe = <records>
             <record>
                 <id>1</id>
                 <name>name</name>
                 <related>
                     <relatedToID>1</relatedToID>
                     <relatedToName>some name</relatedToName>
                 </related>
             </record>
         </records>

    For Each el As XElement In xe.<record>.<related>.Elements
        xe.<record>.LastOrDefault.Add(el)
    Next

    xe.<record>.<related>.Remove()
```

Produces

```
<records>
  <record>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>name</name>
    <relatedToID>1</relatedToID>
    <relatedToName>some name</relatedToName>
  </record>
</records>
```

Comment: This is working well to remove the elements from the related level but the XML string has 39 instances of the `<record>` element which the `relatedToName` element should be going into, instead of going into the respective parent record all of them are being added to the final record.

Comment: Figured it out, instead of going `LastOrDefault` I have used `el.Parent.Parent.Add(el)`

Answer (score 0):

Exists various approaches, but start from this to understand the mechanism.

```
Private Sub MoveChildToParent()

    Dim mxmlString As String = "<records>
                                <record>
                                    <id>1</id>
                                    <name>name</name>
                                    <related>
                                        <relatedToID>1</relatedToID>
                                        <relatedToName>some name</relatedToName>
                                    </related>
                                </record>
                               </records>"


    Try

        Dim mXdoc As Xml.XmlDocument = New Xml.XmlDocument
        mXdoc.LoadXml(mxmlString)

        Dim mdocElement As Xml.XmlElement = mXdoc.DocumentElement

        If mdocElement IsNot Nothing AndAlso mdocElement.HasChildNodes Then

            Dim relateds As Xml.XmlNodeList = mdocElement.GetElementsByTagName("related")

            If relateds IsNot Nothing AndAlso relateds.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = relateds.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1


                    If relateds(i).HasChildNodes Then

                        Dim childs As Xml.XmlNodeList = relateds(i).ChildNodes

                        For j As Integer = childs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                            relateds(i).ParentNode.AppendChild(childs(j))
                        Next

                        relateds(i).ParentNode.RemoveChild(relateds(i))


                    End If



                Next
            End If

            Console.WriteLine(mXdoc.OuterXml)

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```